# how to check condition first only perform action in getview()?

Tags: android, baseadapter

Suppose is like that

> image          word

but now become like that

> image
>
> word

The image and word stack together when beginning, when i slide the listview, it only change to

> image          word

This is the getview in baseadapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_alllatestnewslist, parent,
                false);

    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.image_alllatestnewstitle);
    imageview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    TextView titletext = (TextView) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.text_particularlatestnewstitle);

    if (!imagepath[position].toString().equals("no picture")) {

        titletext.setPadding(imageview.getWidth() + 5, 0, 0, 0);
        imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(imagepath[position], imageview);
    } else {
        imageview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageview.setImageDrawable(null);
        titletext.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    titletext.setText(title[position].toString());
    return vi;
}
```

How to make it check first then set the padding only display?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(position == 0){
   // enter code here
}
else{
   //enter code here
}
```

Comment: i want check entire list item first display all.